# SSRS how to display Hindi numbers

Tags: ssrs-2012

is there a way to display **hindi** numbers in SSRS like 
 **(۰ - ۱ - ۲ - ۳ - ٤ - ٥ - ٦ - ٧ - ۸ - ۹)**

Answer (score 0):

In SSRS, there is no such way to convert data from one language to another, for instance if the data is being retrieved from database in French language you can't change that data to English or any other language. One thing which you can do is, you can store your numbers in Hindi format at database level and retrieve them via query or stored procedure to show them in your SSRS report.

Following link can help:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/2a4ca3a3-49e9-4475-a9a4-a5b1e5d0fba1/multi-language-reports-ssrs?forum=sqlreportingservices